# saving a string array to a file error

Tags: android

How to format directory in android project folder as `jvm` can't see `datass.txt`  or sometimes `logcat` says read only file...(i am putting datass.txt in main project root)

i am passing an array of strings and want to save it to a file datass.txt so i can retrieve data when internet is not connected

```
public void FileWrite(String[]  temp) throws IOException{
        File m = new File("datass.txt");
     final String[] descs = temp ;
     DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new
                BufferedOutputStream(
                  new FileOutputStream(m)));


     for (int i = 0; i < 31; i ++) {

            out.writeUTF(descs[i]);

        }
}
```

Comment: where is your file? If you are trying to access external files, you may need to add permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add File Writing Permission in your `AndroidManiFest.xml` file.

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Please visit this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) for various other permission set.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you could a Index out of bound exception i am not sure but to guard  your self change the for loop header to this

```
for(int i =0; i < descs.length ; ++i)
```